# How can I restart supervisord on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I currently use the additional-supervisord config file to add a few commands to run with supervisord on Google Cloud App Engine.

However, now I need to restart the supervisord service. How can I do that on App Engine?

Thanks

Comment: Is it running on Flex or standard?

Comment: The environment is Flex - PHP Laravel

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/how-instances-are-managed).

> All flexible instances are restarted on a weekly basis. During restarts, critical, backwards-compatible updates are automatically rolled out to the underlying operating system. Your application's image will remain the same across restarts.

Unfortunately right now there is no feature in GCP that allows to configure the restart in GAE flex.
If you want to do that I suggest you to open a FR in the [issuetracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and start the issue in order to be notified for further updates.